# 32-bit program exec() a 64-bit program

Tags: linux, exec, system-calls, cpu-architecture, shellcode

On my Debian amd64 system, I am trying to run tests of 32-bit exploit payloads on sample programs.  I know these payloads work as I have tested them in a 32-bit virtual machine.

All of the necessary libraries are installed to run a 32-bit or 64-bit program.

However, when the shellcode executes `int 80h` to call `exec("/bin/sh", ...)`, the system call fails, returning an error code of -2 (ENOENT).

Modification of the shellcode to execute another 32-bit program results in the shellcode working as expected.

So, is there any way to `exec()` a 64-bit program from a 32-bit program?

Comment: Are you sure you have the correct path to the executable, and that all libraries for the executable are present?

Comment: Yes.  I'm executing /bin/sh.  I'm sure that will work :)

Comment: What system call number are you using? They're not the same on Linux between x86 32-bit and 64-bit.

Comment: 0xb.  I would assume that a 64-bit kernel would still use 32-bit system call numbers if the call came through an `int 80h` and not `syscall` instruction for backwards compatibility reasons.

Answer (score 0):

It works when using the `execl` library function.

It may be difficult to call a library function from shell code, but you can try to trace its execution in a normal program and see how to write shell code that does the same.